# Access sdk.dir value in build.gradle after project evaluation

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a custom task in my build.gradle file that does bytecode transformations on class files before getting dex'd that looks like this:

```
task droidcook(type: JavaExec) {
    main 'org.tsg.android.asm.Main'
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    android.applicationVariants.each { variant ->
        variant.javaCompile.doLast {
            project.tasks.droidcook.configure {
                classpath variant.javaCompile.classpath
                classpath "build/classes/" + variant.dirName
                classpath sdk.dir + "/platforms/android-19/android.jar"
                classpath "compile-libs/droidcook.jar"
                args "build/classes/" + variant.dirName
                args "com.example"
                // args "-debug"
                // args "-asmifier"
            }
            project.tasks.droidcook.execute()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with the above is the `classpath sdk.dir + ...` line where `sdk.dir` isn't evaluated appropriately. To get this working, I currently have to hard code the path to the `android.jar`.

Bonus points if you can answer with an appropriate value to replace `android-19` with for accessing a platform specific `android.jar` based on project configuration. :D

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I don't see a published API to expose sdk.dir to your build file, so I just cribbed the code from https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/d69964104aed4cfae5052028b5c5e57580441ae8/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/Sdk.groovy to read it manually. As for replacing android-19, if I read android.compileSdkVersion I get that exact string. I'm not sure that this is a published API either, so it may be subject to change and breakage in future versions of the Android Gradle plugin.

With that said, this works for me:

```
afterEvaluate {
    def rootDir = project.rootDir
    def localProperties = new File(rootDir, "local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        def androidJarPath = sdkDir + "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"
        print androidJarPath + "\n"
    }
}
```

If there's no local.properties, this code is going to fail. If you care about that case, you can copy more code from Sdk.groovy to mimic its behavior in trying to find a reasonable default.

Comment: much appreciated, I was suffering from gradle burnout :D IIRC from investigating this issue in the past, the problem was that the sdk directory var is instantiated after my `afterEvaluate` and thus why it wasn't available. So manually loading it is likely the only solution currently and this works good enough for cross platform devel.

Comment: println "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}" works on 1.5.0

Answer (score 20):

There's a much simpler way, although it isn't documented, so it probably isn't officially supported.

```
println "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}"
```

Oddly this method only seems to be available for certain versions of the gradle plugin.  It isn't available in the commit linked above by Scott.  If the above code doesn't work, then try this:

```
println "${android.plugin.getSdkFolder().getAbsolutePath()}"
```

For completeness, here's how to get the `ndk.dir` variable, too:

```
println "${android.plugin.getNdkFolder().getAbsolutePath()}"
```

Comment: println "${android.getSdkDirectory().getAbsolutePath()}"  works on 1.5.0

Answer (score 7):

As of android gradle plugin v2.1.2, this is what I use in my gradle script:

```
android.ndkDirectory.path
android.sdkDirectory.path
```

For example to explicitly launch `ndk-build`:

```
task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {
    commandLine android.ndkDirectory.path+'/ndk-build', '-C', file('src/main').absolutePath
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
String androidJar = android.getBootClasspath()[0]
```

Assuming you're using SDK 21, this would set '<path-to-SDK>/platforms/android-21/android.jar' into variable *androidJar* (the SDK version selection performed automatically).

The next step would obviously be replacing 'classpath sdk.dir ...' etc. with:

```
classpath androidJar
```