# How to NOT hardcoded project settings

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm making a simple android application and i want share the repo with other developers but i want write settings to external file and use into the android Code, this is possible with gradle?

example i want put in a file `project_settings.gradle` something like

```
APP_HOST=192.168.0.1
```

and in any place of my code i want use something like

```
String url = "http://" + BuildConfig.APP_HOST
```

that way i can share a `project_settings.gradle.dist` with the others developers

Comment: You may set this IP address as an environment variable. Or if specifically this is You own IP address You can get it via groovy script.

Comment: You can crib this for code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203787/access-sdk-dir-value-in-build-gradle-after-project-evaluation/20272398#20272398

Comment: @ScottBarta I'm really new with gradle please provide me a example as an answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try to set `resValue` in your `build.gradle`. This will create Android resources that will be available to access through your code.

https://plus.google.com/+XavierDucrohet/posts/UVKA58MZV3J

For example:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21

    resValue "string", "country", "US"
    resValue "string", "oauth_token", "some_token"
}
```

In your code if you need to access `country`, call `context.getString(R.string.country)`